# Android 3.0 Honeycomb: How to enable/disable Menu Items in Action Bar?

Tags: menu, android-3.0-honeycomb

it's pretty easy to disable a menu item in XML:

```
<item android:id="@+id/men_1" 
    android:title="@string/men_1" 
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_1"
    android:enabled="false"/>
```

It's also pretty easy to change it via code on a <3.0 app:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
  super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

  MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.men_1);
  item.setEnabled(false);

  return true;
}
```

But how would I do it on Android 3.x? 
I want to disable menu options depending on the Fragment shown.

Kind regards,
jellyfish

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Pretty much the same but put code into the fragment instead, note different method signature.

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item= menu.findItem(R.id.men_1);
    item.setEnabled(false);
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

So the fragment takes responsibility for inflating the menu etc.

**Edit** Note the need to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`

Comment: Thank you! It didn't work, though, until I a added a call to "setHasOptionsMenu(true)" on the Fragment.

Comment: For anyone else coming here looking you also have to override onCreateOptionsMenu in the activity. Something like this: @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
       
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        
        return true;
    }

Comment: Is it really recommended to disable action items instead of just hide them? as a user, I don't think i'd like to have action items just staying around that I can't click...